Differently defined Cesàro summability implies Abel summability
I am trying to solve the Exercise 10 of Section 5.2 of the book `Multiplicative Number Theory I. Classical Theory' by Montgomery & Vaughan. In the exercise, they define the Cesàro summability of order $k$ as follows.

A series $\sum a_n$ is (C, $k$) summable to $a$, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n\le x}a_n\left(1-\frac{n}{x}\right)^k = a$.

Then they asked to show that $\sum a_n = a$ (C, $k$) implies that $\sum a_n = a$ (A). I have tried this by finding a kind of `regular' integral transform, in analogy with Silverman-Toeplitz Theorem. I could see that, if one justifies interchange of integration and summation, then we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nr^n = \int_0^\infty K_k(x,r)\sum_{n\le x}a_n\left(1-\frac{n}{x}\right)^kdx$$ for $|r|<1$, where $$K_k(x,r) = \frac{(-\log r)^{k+1}x^kr^x}{k!}.$$ (If one wishes, I would include this calculation in the post.) This will be possible by Fubini-Tonelli theorem, if we assume merely that $\sum a_nr^n$ converges absolutely for all $|r|<1$. But I could not show this.
I know that in the book 'Divergent Series'  by Hardy, there is alternative definition of Cesàro summability using repeadted partial sums. In that case it is easy to see that $a_n$ has polynomial growth from (C, $k$) summability. So we can show that (C, $k$) summability implies Abel summability. However, our definition is quite different from Hardy's, and I could not prove that they are equivalent.
Actually, I tried to construct counterexamples, too. For $x = N\in\mathbb{N}$, $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n\left(1-\frac{n}{N}\right)^k = \frac{1}{N^k}\sum_{n+m=N}a_nm^k =: \frac{c_N}{N^k}$$ gives the description of $c_N$ by Cauchy product, so we can think of formal power series  operation $$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nr^n \right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}m^kr^n\right) = \sum_{N=1}^{\infty}c_Nr^N,$$ where $c_N\sim aN^k$. Taking $k=3$ and $c_N=N^3-N^2$ (so that $c_N\sim N^3$ and $c_1 = 0$), I got $$\sum_{N=1}^{\infty}c_Nr^N = \frac{2r^2(r+2)}{(1-r)^4}$$ and $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}m^3r^m = \frac{r(r^2+4r+1)}{(1-r)^4}$$ so that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nr^n = \frac{2r(r+2)}{r^2+4r+1}$$ (so in particular, we have $a_n = -(-2-\sqrt{3})^n-(-2+\sqrt{3})^n$) for $|r|<2-\sqrt{3}$, but not outside the region. This implies that we have (weak) (C, $3$) summability (since we only take care when $x\in\mathbb{N}$), but the series $\sum a_nr^n$ is not even defined for all $0<r<1$. This looks like a counterexample, but I cannot show that this is indeed (C, $3$) summable in the above sense.
Hence my question is,


Is there other approach which solves this exercise?
Or is there a method to prove that $a_n$ is polynomially bounded, or $\sum a_nr^n$ converges absolutely for $|r|<1$, from our (C, $k$) summability?
Can we show that our definition of (C, $k$) summability is equivalent to Hardy's (which is the same one in the Wikipedia)?
Does the above $a_n$ serves as a counterexample?


I would appreciate any answer for at least one of these questions.

Along with "Divergent Series" by Hardy,
"The general theory of Dirichlet's series", by Hardy and Riesz, is also a good reference of this and related topics.
For your questions, I will answer Q2 and give a direction for Q3.
Q2. follows from Theorem 21 of the mentioned book by Hardy and Riesz. The idea is to use $k$th difference of sequences.
If $\sum a_n$ is $(C,k)$ summable to $a$, then
$$
\sum_{n\leq N} a_n(N-n)^k = aN^k + o(N^k).
$$
We put $N$, $N+1/k$, $\ldots$, $N+k/k = N+1$ in place of $N$ above. Then take $k$th differences both sides, obtaining for some positive $c_k$,
$$
\sum_{n\leq N} a_n c_k = a c_k + o(N^k).
$$
Dividing by $c_k$, we have
$$
s_N=\sum_{n\leq N}a_n=a+o(N^k).
$$
Now, use $a_N=s_N-s_{N-1}$ to obtain $a_N=o(N^k)$.
Q3. You might want to run some small cases for $k$ and obtain a pattern. You will see from the pattern, two definitions' equivalence follows.

Thanks! I once tried difference technique, but I think I was lost in calculation. This argument makes it simple.
